# Feasibility of dynamically increase in no. of tables and rows in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert many rows to one table OR insert rows separately to many table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999641/insert-many-rows-to-one-table-or-insert-rows-separately-to-many-table)

Which is better 100 tables with 10,000 rows or 1,000 tables with 1,000 rows?

The above question is just a base.Its not completed without the conditions below.

**Conditions:**

- R1-No. of rows in first case.
- R2-No. of rows in second case.
- T1-No. of tables in first case.
- T2-No. of tables in second case.
- R1 and R2 increases dynamically(drastically),above given limit are samples.
- T1 is constant.
- T2 is dynamically increase (proportional to r1)
- Don't care about table management and simplicity of database.
- **Only interested in minimum query execution time and minimum server load time.**
- **Database - MySql**
- Language - PHP

**Problems:**

- Query execution time and server load time(Minimum RAM usage).
- Feasibility of dynamically increase in no. of tables in database.
- Feasibility of dynamically increase in no. of rows in a table.

*Along with answers Database tricks for above also invited.*

Comment: `1` table with `1,000,000` rows.

Comment: Please read the above question/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999641/insert-many-rows-to-one-table-or-insert-rows-separately-to-many-table If it is similar to the problem you have, then no need to search further. Keep the tables' number as low as necessary for normalization (5, 40, 100, whatever your need is) but constant and let the number of rows grow indefinitely.

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Confessions-The-Shopping-Cart.aspx

Comment: This looks like yet another cheater. Honestly people try to do your own homework. You can't succeed professionally when you cheat the learning process.

Comment: Who told this is home work. I made the question into such a way that it can be under stood by any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot to your question, and it would help to have more information, but here are some of my thoughts:

- The language interfacing with the database is generally not a factor -- you should work as hard as possible to limit the number of connections and messages required (i.e. use join instead of communicating with PHP twice), but since good design is doing as much data selection/sorting work on the DB side as possible (because [that's what they're for](http://en.wikiquote.org/w/index.php?title=Thumb_Wars&section=2))
- If all of the tables have the same structure, then you're often better off with one table when dealing with massive selects -- `UNION`, at least in my experience, is generally a slow beast.
- If you're really concerned about accessing only a small subset of the data at once, then I would recommend keeping everything in fewer tables and create views.
- `Don't care about table management and simplicity of database` is a bad policy. All of the best practices of programming are true for db design. Remember, someone who has no idea what you were thinking will inherit this project, and that might be you.

Personally, I think that quite a few of us have had experience with the 1M line table, and I know that I, for one, would not have wanted to deal with that as a series of `UNION`s, `OR`s and `JOIN`s. At least, not when it was all the same table design.

Answer (score 1):

Since a million rows is a tiny, tiny table why would you even consider breaking it up into 100 tables or 1000 tables?